# What to do about my own old posts with broken (La)TeX?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

The recent change in the MathJax rendering engine broke quite a few of my older posts in which I used `\\[` and `\\]` for delimiting displayed math. I'm used to using `\[` instead of `$$` in my LaTeX-documents and thus did this here, too (by the way, this is in accordance with the suggestions of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1166) on tex.SE).

It appears that this isn't rendered properly anymore, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/from-norm-to-scalar-product/20382#20382) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23533/how-to-prove-that-the-sequence-of-x-n-1-frac12-frac13-frac1/23536#23536) among many others.

What should I do about this issue? I'm a bit reluctant to fix this myself manually (admittedly, laziness on my part is not the least of reasons). Is there an easy fix or should I simply ignore it?

**PS.** I became aware of this issue due to an edit of Didier Piau to one of my older answers (thanks for that, by the way!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added \[ as a Mathjax delimiter, it was missing in the latest upgrade.  This should go out with the next build.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, *not quite* perfect, though. Shouldn't it be a *displayed* math delimiter instead of just a math delimiter? The posts are human readable again, but the intent of using `\\[` clearly is to get a displayed math environment.

Comment: Ah yes - displayed math it will be in the next deploy.

Comment: Very good. Let me add that I **really** appreciate your extremely prompt reactions, this is as perfect and helpful support as one could possibly wish for. Thanks!